# How to change the template file of a block progammatically

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to change the template file of a block through code? 
I understand overriding the template file in theme but I want to override it on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin on `getTemplate()` Method for override a phtml file.

At Magento, if a block has a  **phtml** file then it must be called `getTemplate()` method to render the  Block outPut.So if you want to change template file on a conditioning base then you can use Plugin.

Create after  Plugin `afterGetTemplate`()    on  `getTemplate()` function. changes the template as per as your condition.

**Define plugin at di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="{YourBlockClassFullnamewithNameSpace}">
        <plugin name="change_the_temnplate"
                type="{YourPluginClass}"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

```
<?php
namespace {PluginNameSpace};

class {PluginClassname}
{


    public function afterGetTemplate(
        \YourBlockClassFullnamewithNameSpace} $subject,
        $templateFile
    ) {
        if({YourCondtion}){
        return '{Vendorname}_{ModuleName}::{templateLocation}/{templateFilename}.phtml';
    }
        return $templateFile;
    }
}
```